# Using Crispy Forms on Django how do I add an address field?

Tags: python, django

from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

```
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 
              'email', 
              'first_name',
              'last_name',
              'password1', 
              'password2',
        )

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(UserRegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
    user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']



    if commit:
        user.save()

    return user
```

class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

```
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email']
```

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']